# Jsf Related Issue

Tags: jsf

I am getting issue somthing h:outputText and h:inputText both are displaying values but they are collapse the multiple whitespaces into single white space

for that i tried with style="white-space:pre" but it also not working
so i am adding   in between strings

String str="hi & nbsp jsf" and

while displaying it shows in input text box with value "hi & nbsp ;jsf" not "hi jsf" So, what should i have to do so that that it will display without "& nbsp;"

actually i have put that space between & nbsp; because here it will replaceing with white space

I don't want  with escape="false" for displaying because at some place i need h:inputText. In h:inputText there is no option for escape attribute

any other permanent solution for white Space Issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the code of nbsp, because nbsp is not an entity automatically declared like in html pages.
The code is **160**, so you can use `&#160;` .
Alternatively, you can declare an entity at the top of your page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
[<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]>
```

and you are free to use `&nbsp;`

Comment: can u have other permanent easy solution for this other then & nbsp; and & #160; because i have to change in many files

Comment: if your text with embdedded spaces comes from a bean, i don't see an easy solution other than using a <pre> tag, e.g.; <pre>#{bean.yourString}</pre>. Then you can easily stylize <pre> with css.

Comment: i am having a problem only with h:inputText where nothing is working i tried with both & nbsp; and & #160; i solved for h:outputtext but in h:inputText is in disable mode later i can edit that value their it will creating this issue.

Comment: <h:inputText value="Hi& #160;& #160;& #160;jsf"> working but when i displaying it from bean and in output & #160; showing

Comment: h:inputText preserve spaces: if you've <h:inputText value="#{bean.text}"/> and in your bean the getText method return, say, "sample    string", the multiple spaces between 'sample' and 'string' are preserved. Html collapse spaces only out of input controls.

Comment: but  if i want to display space also then what i have to do

Comment: but collapsing of multiple space is happening in h:inputText box also

Comment: String str="Hi           jsf";  <h:inputText value="#{bean.str}" disable="true">    while display it showing "hi jsf"

Comment: when i am refressing the complete jsf page then the display is fine with multiple space but when i am reRendering something at that time the multiple space collapse into single space

Comment: can u tell me ur mail id so that i can explain you complete situation