# NullPointerException from RestoreViewPhase.notifyAfter

Tags: jsf

I'm getting the following error whenever I try to view JSF pages that contain forms.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.notifyAfter(RestoreViewPhase.java:288)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:110)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
```

What does this mean?

This problem started when I tried to use validators on my form fields. So I removed all the validators, but still the problem is not going away.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what version of JSF are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be this logged issue: http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1764

If that is the case then it should be fixed in JSF version 2.1.

Comment: I see... Does that mean I have to update? But I was wondering... Things have been working fine before, and suddenly they're not. I mean, I didn't change versions or anything... Thanks for replying. :)

Comment: I don't know why it was working before but I would try updating to at least 2.1 and see if the error goes away

Comment: Sorry I don't. To get it to work you can try replacing the &nbsp; with the ascii code: &#160; http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm.

Comment: Also check out the answer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576025/jsf-related-issue. If you want to use &nbsp; you can declare an ENTITY at the top of your page